# Using a shared pointer that points to a class of vectors<Mat>, as a function parameter

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

the code snippets illustrated below only serve to help explain how the code works, the entire program that can be used to replicate the problem can be found at the bottom of the Question! Thanks in advance!

I am currently busy coding a security surveillance system in C++ for a project. I am using the RTSP to receive the images.

As soon as I receive te images I use the push_back() command to push the images into a vector that is stored in a class, an example of the class can be seen below:

```
class Temporary_Stacks
{
    public:
    std::vector<cv::Mat>Temp_Stack0;
    std::vector<cv::Mat>Temp_Stack1;
};
std::shared_ptr<Temporary_Stacks>Temporary_Stacks_ptr = std::make_shared<Temporary_Stacks>();
```

I then create a shared pointer. The shared pointer will be passed as one of the arguments to the function. I decided to do this because it might use less processing power to send a pointer in comparison to sending a vector of images.
The pushback command looks like this:

```
Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0.push_Back(Image.clone())
```

When the size of the stack reaches a certain size, I want to send the stack to a saving function that will save these images for me: The reason I want to make a saving function is because I want to place it on a separate thread since it takes long to save images and I want the program to run very fast(When the images are being saved, then the other stack is going to be used to store the images so long).

When the number of images that are kept in Temp_Stack0 reaches a certain value then the following command is called:

```
which_Temp_Stack = Save(Temporary_Stacks_ptr, which_Temp_Stack);
```

And the "Save" function looks like this:

```
void Save(std::shared_ptr<Temporary_Stacks> Temporary_Stacks_ptr)
{
   for(int y = 0; y <=(Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0.size;y++);
   {
   Output.write(Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0[y];
   }
}
```

I know that the images are correctly pushed onto the Temp_Stack0, But it seems that when it is sent as a parameter to the "Save" function, then it does not work and it is as if there is no data saved in that stack. Any pointers?

The entire code that will display the problem can be seen below:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//Constant Variables

//Constant Variables
//Variables
int img_ctr = 0;
int Temp_Stack_Size = 15;
int width = 300;
int height = 300;
bool which_Temp_Stack = 0;

Mat Image;
class Temporary_Stacks
{
public:
    std::vector<cv::Mat>Temp_Stack0;
    std::vector<cv::Mat>Temp_Stack1;
};
std::shared_ptr<Temporary_Stacks>Temporary_Stacks_ptr = std::make_shared<Temporary_Stacks>();

//Variables
VideoWriter Output("Output.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, Size(width, height), true);

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std::this_thread;

cv::VideoCapture Cap_Foscam(0);

int Save(std::shared_ptr<Temporary_Stacks>Temporary_Stacks_ptr, bool which_stack)
{
    if (!which_stack)//Now the Temp_stack0 is being filled.
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= (Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0.size() - 1); y++)
        {
            cout << "HOPES0\n";
            Output.write(Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0[y]);
        }
    Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0.clear();
    }

    if (which_stack)//Now the Temp_stack1 is being filled.
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= (Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack1.size() - 1); y++)
        {
            cout << "HOPES1\n";
            Output.write(Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack1[y]);
        }
    Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack1.clear();
    }
    if (which_stack == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

void Get_New_frame()
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    while (1)
    {
        Cap_Foscam.grab();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.05s);
    }
}

void Display_Images_Real_Time()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (Cap_Foscam.isOpened())
        {
            if (Cap_Foscam.retrieve(Image))
            {
                imshow("Foscam Real Time Feed", Image);
                waitKey(1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Connecting...\n";
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int width = Cap_Foscam.get(3);
    int height = Cap_Foscam.get(4);
    Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0.reserve(Temp_Stack_Size);
    Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack1.reserve(Temp_Stack_Size);

    std::thread NEWEST_FRAME(Get_New_frame);
    std::thread Real_Time_Video(Display_Images_Real_Time);
    VideoWriter Output("Output.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, Size(width, height), true);

    while (1)
    {
        img_ctr++;
        while (!Cap_Foscam.isOpened())
        {
            cv::VideoCapture Cap_Foscam(0);
            std::cout << "Connecting...\n";
        }

        while (Cap_Foscam.isOpened())
        {
            std::cout << img_ctr << endl;
            img_ctr++;            

            if (img_ctr >= Temp_Stack_Size)
            {
                which_Temp_Stack = Save(Temporary_Stacks_ptr, which_Temp_Stack);

                //for (int y = 0; y <= (Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0.size() - 1); y++)
                //{
                //    cout << "HOPES1\n";
                //    Output.write(Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0[y]);
                //}

                //THE COMMENTED CODE ABOVE(LINE 144 TO 148) CAN BE USED TO SEE IF THE IMAGES ARE LOADED INTO THE CLASS, THIS IS ONLY TO SEE FOR YOURSELF THAT THE PUSH_BACK COMMAND WORKES//

                std::cout << "Saved\n";
                img_ctr = 0;
            }
            Cap_Foscam.retrieve(Image);
            if (!which_Temp_Stack)
            {
                Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack0.push_back(Image.clone());
            }
            else
            {
                Temporary_Stacks_ptr->Temp_Stack1.push_back(Image.clone());
                //cout << "TEST";
            }

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you intentionally declare one global `Output` object and one local to `main`?

Comment: I am quite new to coding, I know that it is not completely correct to do so, but when I took it out it gave me errors, so for the time being I kept it in.

Comment: You could pass the object from `main` to `Save` via reference: `int Save(VideoWriter& Output, std::shared_ptr<Temporary_Stacks>Temporary_Stacks_ptr, bool which_stack)` `which_Temp_Stack = Save(Output, Temporary_Stacks_ptr, which_Temp_Stack);`

Comment: So...you kept it in because you didn't understand the errors, not because you knew it was the right thing to do? The errors were probably trying to tell you something. And by "took it out" you never elaborated *which one* you took out. I surmise you removed the global, which would naturally puke since no one would except `main` would have a clue what `Output` was at that point. Perchance, did you take option(b) and instead remove the local in main ? Or stand up a reference arg to `Save` that could use `Output` from `main`? Either would work, the latter preferably.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought about also passing the VideoWriter& Output also as a parameter. It works now. I will also look at the declaration of the VideoWriter function so it is not declared in the main and globally. Thank you for the help!